# How do solr implement filter search

Tags: search, solr

Can anyone point me to the piece of solr source code which performs filter query (excecuting the fq=).

Comment: It's Lucene that does the actual search. Or do you mean where Solr passes filter queries to Lucene?

Comment: Yes. In this case I want to know where solr calls lucene for fq. I also want to know how the filter search executed in lucence if it is different from general query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr's main façade to Lucene is [SolrIndexSearcher](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/SolrIndexSearcher.java?view=markup). In particular the [getDocListC](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/SolrIndexSearcher.java?view=markup#l1028) function seems to do the actual passing to Lucene.

Filter queries and other parameters are passed via a [QueryCommand](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/search/SolrIndexSearcher.QueryCommand.html) class, you can see that filter queries is simply a list of `org.apache.lucene.search.Query`, just like the "main query".